# When fail function is invoked when creating an ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

Given : When making an Ajax request with jQuery, a failure callback gets invoked in case there is any error while making the request.

Can you explain what does it mean "while making the request" ? Can you give me examples.

in other words, when does the fail function is invoked ?

Answer (score 0):

when your response server do not return you success http code, it will invoke the fail function, especially the server errors and client errors response.

**HTTP response status codes**

HTTP response status codes indicate whether a specific HTTP request has been successfully completed. Responses are grouped in five classes:

```
1) Informational responses (100–199)
2) Successful responses (200–299)
3) Redirects (300–399)
4) Client errors (400–499)
5) Server errors (500–599)
```